# Do the nilpotent linear operators form a Lie algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

For a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ will the space of nilpotent linear operators on $V$ be closed under the commutator bracket?

Comment: No, think of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_2(K)$. But you can take the nilpotent operators of strictly upper-triangular form with respect to a basis of $V$. This is the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{n}_m(K)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A counterexample exists in dimension $2$:

Let $X=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $Y=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$, then $XY-YX=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.